# What is object.keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, properties

I remember that `object.keys` return keys of the object. In my code I expect it to return the strings that hold the questions in the `questions` array of objects. Instead it returns the array of possible answers.

How did object.keys return the property of the object?

```
//var  answersCopy = questions[correctAnswerIndex]
[Object.keys(questions[correctAnswerIndex])[0]];
```

Is it the set up? Also I did start playing with it like in the paper where I just isolate everything and then combine those two again but still I don't get why object.keys gets the properties of that.

[image: the Paper (Captains Log: 1#)]

```
function populateRoundAnswers(questions, correctAnswerIndex, correctAnswerIndex2) {
  var ANSWER_COUNT = 4;


  var  GAME_LENGTH = 5;
     correctAnswerIndex= 0;
     correctAnswerIndex2= 2;

questions = [
{
    "Reindeer have very thick coats, how many hairs per square inch do they have?": [
        "13,000",
        "1,200",
        "5,000",
        "700",
        "1,000",
        "120,000"
    ]
},
{
    "The 1964 classic Rudolph The Red Nosed Reindeer was filmed in:": [
        "Japan",
        "United States",
        "Finland",
        "Germany"
    ]
},
 {
    "Santa's reindeer are cared for by one of the Christmas elves, what is his name?": [
        "Wunorse Openslae",
        "Alabaster Snowball",
        "Bushy Evergreen",
        "Pepper Minstix"
    ]
},
{
    "If all of Santa's reindeer had antlers while pulling his Christmas sleigh, they would all be:": [
        "Girls",
        "Boys",
        "Girls and boys",
        "No way to tell"
    ]
},
{
    "What do Reindeer eat?": [
        "Lichen",
        "Grasses",
        "Leaves",
        "Berries"
    ]
}    
];
  var  answersCopy = questions[correctAnswerIndex][Object.keys(questions[correctAnswerIndex])[0]];
return answersCopy;
}

populateRoundAnswers();
```

Comment: You should either use a hashtable like object or an array with static key objects.

Comment: Nice picture of handwritten code.

Comment: Jonas, hashtable  is COOL man thanks for sharing!!!

Much love and Be Blessed  

P.S TGrif, thanks  even though I can only read my hand writing.

K.C Diez, L.E.A.F Space Board

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys returns an array of enumerable properties found in an object.

In your case, this line of code:

```
  var  answersCopy = questions[correctAnswerIndex][Object.keys(questions[correctAnswerIndex])[0]];
```

is accessing the answers of a question.

`questions[correctAnswerIndex]` - this returns the first question
`[Object.keys(questions[correctAnswerIndex])[0]]` - this returns `Reindeer have very thick coats, how many hairs per square inch do they have?`

Now looking back at `answersCopy` var, you access the first element in the array and then you're looking at a specific property which returns you the array of answers.

If you want to get the array of an Object's keys, all you have to do is pass an object to the `keys` method of the Object class.

```
var myObj = { name: 'Mike', age: 20 }
console.log(Object.keys(myObj)) // ['name', 'age']
```

Comment: Sergui, thanks man and honestly I figure it out, it's the [ ], 

but thank's  for the Time and attention on my post Sergui

much love and be blessed.

~KC. Diez